# Get region statistics in spring data geode client application

Tags: caching, spring-data-gemfire, spring-boot-data-geode

I need to get the region statistics on apache geode client-cache application.

Setup:
1 locator
1 server
1 client-cache app

All the modules are created using spring.

Cache server will create regions based on the **cache.xml**

Cache.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns="http://geode.apache.org/schema/cache"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://geode.apache.org/schema/cache http://geode.apache.org/schema/cache/cache-1.0.xsd"
       version="1.0" lock-lease="120" lock-timeout="60" search-timeout="300"
       is-server="true" copy-on-read="false">

    <pdx read-serialized="true" persistent="true">
        <pdx-serializer>
            <class-name>
                org.apache.geode.pdx.ReflectionBasedAutoSerializer
            </class-name>
        </pdx-serializer>
    </pdx>

    <region name="track" refid="PARTITION_PERSISTENT_OVERFLOW">
        <region-attributes statistics-enabled="true">
            <compressor>
                <class-name>org.apache.geode.compression.SnappyCompressor</class-name>
            </compressor>
        </region-attributes>
        <index name="trackKeyIndex" from-clause="/track" expression="key" key-index="true"/>
        <index name="trackTransactionNameIndex" from-clause="/track" expression="transactions[*]"/>
    </region>
</cache>
```

Cache-server application

```
@SpringBootApplication
@org.springframework.data.gemfire.config.annotation.CacheServerApplication(name = "cacheServer", locators = "localhost[10334]")
@EnableClusterAware
@EnableCompression
@EnableStatistics
@EnableGemFireProperties(cacheXmlFile = "cache.xml")
public class CacheServerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CacheServerApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Client-cache application

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ClientCacheApplication
@EnableClusterDefinedRegions //Fetch cluster defined regions for @Resource autowired prop
@EnableStatistics
public class GeodeClientApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(GeodeClientApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Component class in client-cache to fetch region statistics.

```
@Component
public class TrackedInsightsCacheService {

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TrackedInsightsCacheService.class);

    @Autowired
    @Resource(name = "track")
    private Region trackRegion;

    public Object getRegionStatistics(){
                RegionAttributes attributes = trackRegion.getAttributes();
                if(attributes.getStatisticsEnabled()) {
                    return trackRegion.getStatistics();
                }
                return null;
            }
    public Object get(String key) {
        return trackRegion.get(key);
    }

    public void put(String key, String value){
        trackRegion.put(key, value);
    }        
}
```

Autowired TrackRegion is LocalRegion. Whenever I do a get call, it first checks the local region then checks the key on server region.

But When I do the getStatistics call, it says statistics are disabled for the region.

What am I missing here?
Is this the proper way to get region statistics.

I'm able to get the cluster statistics through the gfsh command line and output is something like this,

```
gfsh>show metrics
Cluster-wide Metrics

Category  |        Metric         | Value
--------- | --------------------- | -----
cluster   | totalHeapSize         | 4846
cache     | totalRegionEntryCount | 1
          | totalRegionCount      | 1
          | totalMissCount        | 81
          | totalHitCount         | 15
diskstore | totalDiskUsage        | 0
          | diskReadsRate         | 0.0
          | diskWritesRate        | 0.0
          | flushTimeAvgLatency   | 0
          | totalBackupInProgress | 0
query     | activeCQCount         | 0
          | queryRequestRate      | 0.0
```

I have multiple regions in the setup and looking at the cluster wise statistics is not sufficient, so looking for getting region-wise metrics data.

Answer (score 1):

The `getStatistics()` method returns the statistics for the actual `Region` instance. Since you're executing this method on the **client side**, the actual statistics returned will be for the local client `Region`, which is not what you want.

The `gfsh show metrics` command actually retrieves the region statistics using `JMX`, you could check the source code and adapt it to your needs [here](https://github.com/apache/geode/blob/d058f0dd1f23a6339cd0860933e58e428cb9eea7/geode-gfsh/src/main/java/org/apache/geode/management/internal/cli/commands/ShowMetricsCommand.java#L278).

Another option, if you don't want to use `JMX`, would be to write a custom [Geode Function](https://geode.apache.org/docs/guide/113/developing/function_exec/chapter_overview.html) and manually retrieve the statistics you're looking for through the usage of the [StatisticsManager](https://github.com/apache/geode/blob/d058f0dd1f23a6339cd0860933e58e428cb9eea7/geode-core/src/main/java/org/apache/geode/internal/statistics/StatisticsManager.java).

Cheers.